# Pegar parte de uma URL com PHP Explode

Tags: php

Como faço para pegar somente o que esta depois de **?** e antes de **&**?

```
$url = "https://www.dominio.com/login?erro=1&data=2018-03-06";
$url_cod = explode('?', $url);
```

Ali ele esta retornando tudo o que vem depois do ponto de interrogação.

Comment: Para a URL, `?erro=1&data=2018-03-06` ou `?data=2018-03-06&erro=1` são a mesma coisa, então qual valor deveria pegar? E por quê precisa fazer isso?

Comment: Preciso pegar somente o erro=1, é que estou fazendo uma validação via GET em uma página.

Comment: Mas é a URL da própria página ou uma URL qualquer como no exemplo?

Comment: Da própria página. Falei errado, via GET não vai funcionar, pois preciso que ele retorne com a palavra erro, exatamente dessa forma: erro=1

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser pegar os parâmetros passados por GET de uma URL qualquer – não necessariamente a da página atual, que o PHP já disponibiliza em `$_GET` – existem funções próprias para isso:

1. [`parse_url`](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.parse-url.php) recebe uma URL e retorna array com os principais componentes – incluindo a querystring, que é o que interessa aqui.
2. [`parse_str`](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.parse-str.php) é feito para quebrar querystrings em array.

Juntando os dois:

```
$url = "https://www.dominio.com/login?erro=1&data=2018-03-06";
$partes = parse_url($url);
if(!empty($partes['query'])) {
    $vars = [];
    parse_str($partes['query'], $vars);
    var_dump($vars);
}

// Saída:
//
// array(2) {
//   ["erro"]=>
//   string(1) "1"
//   ["data"]=>
//   string(10) "2018-03-06"
// }
```

[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/gu4tXN).

---

Sobre a abordagem que você estava tentando:

> Como faço para pegar somente o que esta depois de ? e antes de &?

Pensando nesse problema de maneira genérica (porque para tratar URLs eu usaria o código acima), é simples resolver com manipulação de strings. Com o `explode` você já conseguiu obter uma string assim:

```
$sua_string = "erro=1&data=2018-03-06";
```

Olhando isso, é só achar o primeiro `&` e pegar tudo que está antes dele:

```
$sua_string = "erro=1&data=2018-03-06";
$pos = strpos($sua_string, '&');
$resultado = substr($sua_string, 0, $pos-1);
echo $resultado; // erro=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Tudo que vier depois do `?` é populado pela super global `$_GET`, assim, caso você queira pegar algum parâmetro na url você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
```

Esse código retornaria o valor `'2018-03-06'`.

Para pegar o erro basta fazer:

```
$erro = $_GET['erro'];
```

Esse código retornaria o valor `1`.

Como você quer o valor com o nome da variável, você pode concatenar o valor com uma string.

```
$erroString = 'erro='.$erro;
```

Comment: Preciso que ele retorne apenas o valor: erro=1

Comment: Editei. Você pode pegar qualquer valor da url, basta passar a key correspondente

Comment: Não preciso apenas do valor, preciso que ele retorne com a palavra erro também.

Comment: Só você concatenar o valor obtido com a string que você quiser. Editei a resposta fazendo isso.

Answer (score 0):

O explode vai transformar a $url_cod num array, para pegar oque está antes bastar colocar:

```
$parte_url = $url_cod[1];
//Ou [0] para oque vem antes
```

Para o '&' você usa o mesmo sistema

Ou caso queira pegar os parâmetros GET, faça como o @Phelipe respondeu acima

```
 $url = "www.google.com?&nome_da_variavel_recebida=123";
 $valor = $_GET['nome_da_variavel_recebida'];
 //Nesse caso $valor seria igual a 123
```